# how to build an integration center for automated lead capturing?

Tags: automation, crm, zapier

[`Here is the reference for integration center`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kCwJ.png)

please show me a path to do the same.
because we are developing a CRM software, we are trying to figure out how it done but still we are in middle of ocean. I guess zapier and webhooks play the key roles but we need a guide from the great developers.